# Infix pattern matching

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

An issue I sometimes encounter when programming in Haskell is sometimes I want to match a pattern against a value, but I'm only interested in a true-false information on whether a value matches a pattern (e.g. a specific data type constructor). For instance:

```
data Color = 
    RGB Int Int Int 
  | Greyscale Int

toHex :: Color -> String
toHex color =
  if isGreyscale color then something
  else somethingElse

  where
  isGreyscale :: Color -> Bool
  isGreyscale (Greyscale _) = True
  isGreyscale _             = False
```

whereas I'd like to do do the pattern matching without creating an unnecessary auxillary function, something along the lines of:

```
toHex :: Color -> String
toHex color =
  if (color ~~ (Greyscale _)) then something
  else somethingElse
```

Is there a specific syntax allowing something similar to the example above? Or perhaps an idiom that would come in handy in such situations?

Comment: Unless we already have a boolean around, `if` is often pretty bad, since it forces us to take our rich data and strip everything away until we have a boolean. `if condition` is essentially a very limited `case condition of True -> ... ; False -> ...`, which unlike the general `case` never binds values to variables -- a key part of pattern matching. In your case, to get a boolean you are throwing away the `value` inside `Grayscale value`, when a `case` would keep it. Don't suffer from [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/)!

Comment: May be interesting reading for you: [A Crossroad at a Branch](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/crossroad.xhtml).

Comment: An ugly but occasionally useful idiom: `if null [ () | Greyscale _ <- color ] ...`

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is (or can be) an infix operator, because a pattern isn't a value; it's syntax.

You are looking for a `case` expression

```
toHex :: Color -> String
toHex color = case color of
               Greyscale _ -> something
               otherwise -> somethingElse
```

though you would more commonly write this as

```
toHex :: Color -> String
toHex (Greyscale _) = something
toHex _ = somethingElse
```

which essentially desugars to the code above.

There is also the `LambdaCase` extension in GHC, which would allow you to write the following, eliminating the otherwise unnecessary variable `color`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}


toHex :: Color -> String
toHex = \case 
          Greyscale _ -> something
          otherwise -> somethingElse
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching in the function definition to determine the value:

```
toHex :: Color -> String
toHex (Greyscale _) = something
toHex _ = somethingElse
```

The first pattern matches a grey scale value regardless of the integer value, and the second clause matches everything else. If `something` and `somethingElse` are functions that require details from the parameter, you can capture those easily:

```
toHex :: Color -> String
toHex (Greyscale g) = something g
toHex (RGB r g b) = somethingElse r g b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multi-way if-expressions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#multi-way-if-expressions) and pattern guards to get almost exactly the syntax you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

toHex :: Color -> String
toHex color =
  if | Greyscale _ <- color -> something
     | otherwise -> somethingElse
```